# Visual studio 2008 error ? "LNK1104 : cannot open file "

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-7

```
Error 1 fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Users\hongo\Documents\VisualStudio2008\Projects\PruebaNodosLcmasmas\Debug\PruebaNodosLcmasmas.exe'    PruebaNodosLcmasmas PruebaNodosLcmasmas
```

This error happens in visual studio 2008 after I rebuild a solution too many times in little time.

After that, I cannot get access to the debug/release folders for up to 3 minutes and that is really "APITA" cause I need to test new changes to the code as I am programming.

Any ideas on how to fix this? I'm using Windows 7 64 bits.

thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by too many times in little time? tried to right click on the solution inside solution explorer and select Clean Solution and build again?

Comment: yes, indeed this happens after doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when your executable is running while you compile. Close your executable. If it refuses to close, find it in task manager and close the process forcefully.

Comment: this is not that case, it also happens after I run the solution so no .exe is opened.

Comment: If the error occurs and I just wait like 3 minutes then its "fixed".
Could this be related with Windows 7 ?

Comment: @HoNgOuRu: when you run the solution the .exe is opened... (unless I missed something)

Comment: @HoNgOuRu: this is unlikely related to Windows 7.

Comment: if I only open the solution just file open project...
and I rebuild it two times then the error appear.
Then if I wait 3 minutes its ok, I can rebuild without any problems...

Comment: It's probably your antivirus software.